# Add ggplot2 option geom_hline as string

Tags: r, string, ggplot2, eval

I have a question regarding ggplot2. Sorry, for not giving example data since the function is called in shiny. If needed, I will try to construct a minimal example without the shiny code. But I hope that the question may be easy and an answer is possible without rerunning the code.

I try to give several  `geom_hline` options to a ggplot function which are created as strings inside a for loop. `struct$Retention` are a few numeric values.

The problem is that `eval(parse(text = horizLine))` tries to evaluate the string and so tries to add `+` strings which results in the following error:

```
Warning: Error in +: non-numeric argument to binary operator
Stack trace (innermost first):
    78: eval [<text>#1]
    77: eval
    76: renderPlot [plots.R#11]
    68: output$ClaimPlot
    1: runApp
```

So what I am searching for is a way to give the string with the `+` function as a option to the ggplot function. 
Or another way to give the options to ggplot.

```
output$ClaimPlot <- renderPlot({
  x    <- readClaimData()
  struct <- readStructData()
  horizLine <- c()
  for( i in 1:length( struct$Retention )) {
        horizLine[i] <- paste("geom_hline(aes(yintercept =", as.numeric(struct$Retention[i]), "))", sep = "")
  }
  horizLine <- paste(horizLine, sep = "", collapse = " + ")
  x <- melt(x, id.vars = c("Year", "ClaimNo"), variable.name = "State", value.name = c("Claim"))
  ggplot(data = x, aes(x=factor(ClaimNo), y=Claim, fill = factor(State))) + 
    geom_bar(colour = "black", stat = "identity") + 
    ylab("Claim Size") +
    xlab("Claim Number") +
    facet_grid(Year ~ .) +
    eval(parse(text = horizLine))
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't just pass the `struct` dataframe to `geom_hline`?

Something like this:

```
ggplot(data = x, aes(x=factor(ClaimNo), y=Claim, fill = factor(State))) + 
    geom_bar(colour = "black", stat = "identity") + 
    ylab("Claim Size") +
    xlab("Claim Number") +
    facet_grid(Year ~ .) +
    geom_hline(data=struct, aes(yintercept=Retention))
```

Depending on what exactly you're looking for, you may have to add other information to `struct` (i.e. the year?)

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was searching for.